# session.upload_progress - Internal Server Error

Tags: php, session

I have very strange problem with these three files:

up1.php -form add file

```
<?php session_start();?>
<form action="up2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="nazwa" />
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" value="plik" />
<input type="submit" name="nazwa" />
</form>
```

up2.php - form

```
<? session_start();
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['nazwa']['tmp_name'], 'up.jpg')) echo "wgrano plik";
?>
```

and up3.php show me transfer:

```
<?php session_start();
$key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") .'plik';
var_dump($_SESSION[$key]);
?>
```

in my php.ini I changed one line:

```
session.upload_progress.cleanup=0;
```

When up1.php send form to up2.php I got error:

**Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request**

and log error:

**[xxx 2014] [error] [client xxx] , referer: xxx/upload1.php**

**[xxx 2014] [error] [client xxx] Premature end of script headers: upload2.php, referer: xxx/upload1.php**

Comment: Are you running PHP as FastCGI? 'cause that has issues to my knowledge...

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the question, made into an answer. I do not take credit for this.

The error is that the ordering of form fields matters. The upload progress input field has to precede the upload file input field.

correct form:

```
<form action="upload2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" value="plik" />
<input type="file" name="nazwa" />
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

incorrect form:

```
<form action="upload2.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="nazwa" />
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" value="plik" />
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```